# why nginx don't use basic types directly?

Tags: c, nginx

the code is from ngx_config.h

```
typedef intptr_t        ngx_int_t;
typedef uintptr_t       ngx_uint_t;
typedef intptr_t        ngx_flag_t;
```

the prototype of intptr_t is int, and the corresponding to uintptr_t is u_int.

seems a sophisticated type hierarchy is set by nginx designer. i am just confused why they don't use basic type directly?

In fact this kind of type hierarchy makes code a bit sophisticated.

i know this hierarchy can make it easy when you try to modify some type from A to B but simply change one line of code which can also lead to better **portability**, that is change typedef A xxtype to typedef B xxtype, but i wonder if this kind of type hierarchy is over used in nginx? anybody here who could any clues about this over use staff?

what's more, you can also tell more benefits or tricks about this kind of design:)

Comment: a kind of trademark?:-)

Comment: @user9000 what is the name of this style? is this good style?

Comment: There's no name, he just made his own style of writing code.  Just like you can invent your own... `typedef intptr_t hugemoew_int_t`...  There's no good or bad, it depends on your taste, I'd rather just use `intptr_t` though.